# Meaning of contains in java/Android

Tags: java, android

First, sending 0 to lit1 and 300 to lit2, the result was Spotted 0/300 lights
then sending 200 to lit1 and the result come Spotted 200/300 lights
then sending 0 to lit2 and the result was Spotted 200/0 lights

Restart (lit1 200 & lit2 300), changing lit1 to 20 & the result was Spotted 20/300 lights
then changing lit1 to 200 & lit2 to 30, result was Spotted 200/30 lights

Restart (lit1 200 & lit2 300), changed lit1 to 0, the result was Spotted 200/300 lights

I've tried so many times and found out every time a > 0 & b > 0 then sending lit1 with 0,
it cannot passing the condition of "!spot.toString().contains(a+"/"+b)".

The code:

```
static SpannableString spot;
static ForegroundColorSpan y;

public class Span {
    static SpannableString SPOT(int lit1, int lit2){
        String a = Integer.toString(lit1), b = Integer.toString(lit2);
        if(spot==null|| !spot.toString().contains(a+"/"+b)){
            y = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
            spot = new SpannableString("Spotted "+d+"/"+b+" lights");
            spot.setSpan(y, 7, 7+d.length()+b.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        return spot;
    }
}
```

Really need help, because I use lots of SpannableString Method.

Answer (score 0):

200 and 300 and 20 all end with "0"

edit:

Maybe I'm not being clear enough. "0/300" is inside of "200/300".

Comment: I tried sending lit1 123 and lit2 456, and when sending lit1 with 0 it really works. But I still don't understand about both ending with "0" because "contains" means everything in a+"/"+b right? Or not? Really appreciate the explanation, so I know how to make the right code.

Comment: "dog" is entirely contained inside of "abadogaba". so "abadogaba".contains("dog") will return true. Likewise "0/300" is entirely contained inside of "200/300".

Comment: @ D.Kupra I see.. omg, there are so many method using contains, which is turns out so different from what I was thought. Omg... Thank you so much for the explanation sir.

Comment: 1 thing still missing.. Why it could be 200/0 from 200/300..? Lol!

Comment: I don't know but it won't be caused by the behavior of spannablestring. And probably doesn't have much to do with string containment because that controls *if* you change spot, not what you change it to. So even if you feel like you got the order correct, the most likely place to look is that you switched lit1 and lit 2.

Comment: Your edited answer, I can see it now! My logic must been messed with 15.000 lines of code (so far). Thanks!